# provide slot value for specific slot in response and resume the conversation

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I am working on lex and want to give slot value in the response which will only be asked if the user enters specific input in the previous slot value. I am trying something but I don't I am doing right or not.

i have following slots in lex.

1. Departure_city
2. Arrival_city
3. Departing (oneway or roundtrip)
4. ReturnDate
5. Date (DepartureDate)
6. Flight Schedule

e.g. if user select Roundtrip then ask for the return date otherwise skip that slot and continue the flow by asking value of the remaining of slots

here is the piece of code that I am doing to fulfill this scenario.

```js
"use strict";

const lexResponses = require("./lexResponse");

const depart = ["one-way", "oneway"];

const buildValidationResult = (isValid, violatedSlot, messageContent) => {
  if (messageContent == null) {
    return {
      isValid: isValid,
      violatedSlot: violatedSlot,
    };
  }
  return {
    isValid: isValid,
    violatedSlot: violatedSlot,
    message: { contentType: "PlainText", content: messageContent },
  };
};

function validateBookaflight(
  Departing,
  ReturnDate
) {
  if (Departing && depart.indexOf(Departing.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
   
     return {
          dialogAction: {
            type: "ElicitSlot",
            intentName: "Bookaflight",
            slots: {
              Departure_city: Departure_city,
              Arrival_city: Arrival_city,
              Departing: Departing,
              ReturnDate: ReturnDate,
            },
            slotToElicit: "ReturnDate",
            message: {
              contentType: "PlainText",
              content: "Please enter return date,(yyyy-mm-dd)",
            },
          },
        }
    };
     return buildValidationResult(true, null, null);
}

function buildFulfilmentResult(fullfilmentState, messageContent) {
  return {
    fullfilmentState,
    message: { contentType: "PlainText", content: messageContent },
  };
}
```

**error:**

```js
An error has occurred: Invalid Lambda 
Response: Received invalid response from 
Lambda: Can not construct instance of 
ElicitSlotDialogAction, problem: 
slotToElicit must not be blank in ElicitSlot 
dialog action at 
[Source: {"sessionAttributes":{},"dialogAction":{"type":"ElicitSlot","intentName":"Bookaflight",
"slots":{"ReturnDate":null,"Departure_city":"london","Flight_schedule":null,"Arrival_city":"lahore","Date":null,
"Departing":"roundtrip",
"undefined":null}}}; line: 1, column: 241]
```

[image]

please tell what i am doing wrong or if you have any issue understanding my requirement.

Comment: You should return all slot values which have been entered, not just "ReturnDate". If you don't return it, the slots are treated as null. If this doesn't help, please post the complete error message.

Comment: @Paradigm i have update the error message and update code. please check.

Comment: Could you confirm what the Lambda function returns by doing a test run from the Lambda console using the same input passed by lex?

Comment: @Paradigm i can share logs with you. in logs it doesn't show any error

Comment: or skipping a slot will also work e.g. if the user enters oneway So, skip the returnDate slot otherwise don't skip that. is this possible?

Comment: Logs would help, just print the response before it is returned. Regarding skipping a slot, that is possible. This can be done by not marking the slot as "Required" and specifying the "slotToElicit" accordingly.

Comment: i didn't mark  Return date as required. So how I can use that if user enter roundtrip????

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224329/discussion-between-tayyab-and-paradigm).

Comment: The error now is just saying you are not passing "SlotToElicit" in the Dialogaction. When manually eliciting an untequired slot, you have to specify which slot by name with "SlotToElicit".

Comment: @JayA.Little as you can see in the code I am passing the slot name in SlotToElicit

Comment: Please check "ReturnDate" in your code again and compare that with the slot name you set up in Lex Console. The error shows what should be "ReturnDate" slot as "undefined". Then nothing after that where your code shows it should have "slotToElicit" and "message".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're seeing seems to be caused due to the `slotToElicit` parameter not being returned to Lex for some reason. To confirm what the Lambda returns to Lex, try running a test invoke of the function using the same input that's passed by the Lex bot.

Additionally, when returning the values of the slots in the Lambda response, if you do not return the values for the other slots, Lex treats them as null. Thus ensure that all slot values that are returned are not `null` and contain the values entered by the user.

Comment: i had ask a new question and share cloudwatch logs to ensure that the slot values that re returned are not null please look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64769925/slottoelicit-must-not-be-blank